# Prime Factoring in Java - Intro Programming

Tags: java, primes, prime-factoring, factoring

Original: So for my intro to programming class, we have to find the prime factors of a range of numbers that the user inputs (i.e. 59-65). The issue with a lot of the solutions here is that they use things that we haven't discussed in class like arrays, continue, etc. It's a pretty basic class. As for the requirements, we have to use a primeFact method/function that we call in the first for loop. She instructed us to use a while and for loop in the method to get the prime factors but everytime I think I have something, it doesn't come out right. Any help is really appreciated and my code is below. I really only need help with the method portion with the algorithm for finding the factors.

Edit: Here is the final solution that I turned in. It works and will give all prime factors of all numbers in a given range of numbers.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PrimeFact {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int start, stop;

    //Get input
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter then two values with the lower value first");
    start = input.nextInt();
    stop = input.nextInt(); 
    input.close();

    //Displays for the start of the loop
    System.out.println("Starting value (at least two digits): "+start);
    System.out.println("Ending value (at least two digits): "+stop);
    System.out.println("Prime factors for numbers between "+start+" and "+stop);

    //Loop for the prime factors
    for (int num = start; num <= stop; num++) {
        primeFact(num);
    }
}

// Method for Prime Factoring
public static void primeFact(int num) {
    int divisor = 2;
    System.out.print(num+" = ");
    while (num>1) {
        if ((num%divisor) == 0) {
            System.out.print(divisor+" x ");    
            num=num/divisor;            
        } else {
            divisor++;
        }
    }
    System.out.print("1");
    System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the `r` tag? What does it mean "it doesn't come out right?"

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void primeFact(int num) {
   System.out.print(num+" = ");
    for(int i=2;i<num;i++)
    {
        if(num%i==0)
        {
            if(isPrime(i))
            {
                System.out.println("Prime Factor for "+num+" is:"+i);
            }
        }

     }
   if(num==2)
     System.out.println("Prime Factor for "+num+" is:"+num);
 }
static boolean isPrime(int num){
  for(int i=2;i<num;i++)
    {
        if(num%i==0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
  }

//if u want use while replace the for loop like
   public static void primeFact(int num) {
   System.out.print(num+" = ");      

    int i=2;
    while(i<num)
    {
        if(num%i==0)
        {
            if(isPrime(i))
            {
                System.out.println("Prime Factor for "+num+" is:"+i);
            }
        }
        i=i+1;
     }
     if(num==2)
     System.out.println("Prime Factor for "+num+" is:"+num);
 }
static boolean isPrime(int num){
  int i=2;
   while(i<num)
    {
        if(num%i==0)
        {
            return false;
        }
     i=i+1;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you're method is pretty close to a solution. but your while loop is invalid.

remember it should be like this:

```
while(<boolean statement>){
    //code here
}
```

I will reference the variable we are checking "primality" for as "num"

here's how to check for factors with a while loop:

```
//remember, num is given to us in the parameters of primeFact(int num).

boolean isPrime = true; //we are optimistic.

//we start at 2 because everything is divisible by one
int posFact = 2; //short for "possible factor"

while(posFact < num){ //this will start at 2, and go to 1 less than num
    if(num % posFact == 0){ // "%" gives us remainder
        isPrime = false; // we now know it's not prime
        System.out.println("The number " + posFact + " is a factor of " + num + ".");
    }
    posFact++; //increments posFact up by 1
}

if(isPrime){ //This will only be true if the number is prime
    System.out.println("The number " + num + " is prime!");
}
```

We can do the exact same thing with a for loop:

```
//remember, num is given to us in the parameters.

boolean isPrime = true; //we are optimistic.

for(int posFact = 2; posFact < num; posFact++){ //posFact's initialization and incrementation was moved here.
    if(num % posFact == 0){ // "%" gives us remainder
        isPrime = false; // we now know it's not prime
        System.out.println("The number " + posFact + " is a factor of " + num + ".");
    }
}

if(isPrime){ //This will only be true if the number is prime
    System.out.println("The number " + num + " is prime!");
}
```